# How to make tail -f show time when line was appended?

Tags: bash, tail

I'd like to know the time when line was appended when file is being `tail -f`'ed.

Is it possible to configure `tail` to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  Try the following:

```
tail -f /tmp/log.txt | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'
```

Comment: If you're dealing with log files that you are creating, it may be better practice to have the logging program add timestamps to the log instead of the above

Comment: Also this will only tell one the time `tail` outputted the line. To see this try `tail --sleep-interval=300 somefile`

Comment: Oops `tail` only pays attention to `--sleep-interval`  when it is not using `inotify`. So my example above should be `tail ---disable-inotify --sleep-interval=3000 -f somefile`